# вывести ряд Фибоначчи с помощью методов js(без применения методов массивов)

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
var n = +prompt( 'значение n', '' );

function fib(n) {
    var a = 1,
        b = 1;
    for (var i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        var c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }

    return b;
}

console.log( fib( n ) );
```

Comment: Ну задача решена - вывод выполнен методом `log` объекта `console`... А вопрос-то собственно в чём?

Comment: вопрос в том, чтобы выводился не n-й член ряда, а весь ряд, включая n-й.

Comment: Ну оберни вывод в цикл... или в функции наполняй массив... или прямо в функции выводи...

Answer (score 1):

Например можно собирать в строку и вернуть её

```js
var n = 4;

function fib(n) {
    var a = 1,
        b = 1
        result = a + ' ' + b + ' ';
    for (var i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        var c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        result += c + ' ';
    }

    return result;
}

console.log( fib( n ) );
```

Comment: при выводе нужно использовать массив

Comment: @user279010 вы же сами написали в заголовке **без применения методов массивов** ... как можно использовать массивы не используя их?